# sed -n //,//p не срабатывает

Tags: bash, sed

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой

```
echo "word1 word2 word3" | sed -n '/word1/,/word3/p';
echo "word1 word2 word3" | sed -n "/word1/,/word3/p";
echo "word1 word2 word3" | sed -n /word1/,/word3/p;
sed -n /word1/,/word3/p <<< "word1 word2 word3";
```

Все эти команды выводят "word1 word2 word3", а должны вроде как " word2 ". Где я ошибся?

**Решено следующим образом:**

```
echo "word1 word2 word3" | sed -n 's/word1\(.*\)word3/\1/p';
```

Comment: sed печатает полученную строку целиком. для вырезки лишнего вам надо использовать замену типа `sed 's/.*\(word2\|word3\).*/\1/'`. Правда так он только одно слово оставит ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашей версии команды, sed ищет строки содержащие word1 или word3.

Для получения " word2 " из "word1 word2 word3" можно воспользоваться следующим выражением:

```
echo "word1 word2 word3" | sed -n 's/word1\(.*\)word3/\1/p';
```

Comment: Спасибо, это работает.